error during the installation of ruamel-yaml-conda
I have a lil problem with the installation of ruamel-yaml-conda.
I have this brand new fridge fresh enviorment for spyder; and while checking dependencies and installing the ones missing I encountered this little obstacle while installing with pip ruamel-yaml-conda.
trying to install the package in the "classic" way, the terminal gives me is this kind of error:
Collecting ruamel-yaml-conda
  Using cached ruamel_yaml_conda-0.15.80.tar.gz (202 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/pn/r4h6wncx1fj97zcdjr2jsxpw0000gn/T/pip-install-9wxy_qdj/ruamel-yaml-conda_cbc16ce42fa94f7b92437d99fa4c8484/ruamel_yaml/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
          from .main import *                               # NOQA
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/pn/r4h6wncx1fj97zcdjr2jsxpw0000gn/T/pip-install-9wxy_qdj/ruamel-yaml-conda_cbc16ce42fa94f7b92437d99fa4c8484/ruamel_yaml/main.py", line 21, in <module>
          from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO, BytesIO, with_metaclass, PY3, nprint
      ImportError: cannot import name 'PY3' from 'ruamel.yaml.compat' (/opt/miniconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/compat.py)
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/pn/r4h6wncx1fj97zcdjr2jsxpw0000gn/T/pip-install-9wxy_qdj/ruamel-yaml-conda_cbc16ce42fa94f7b92437d99fa4c8484/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
          import ruamel_yaml  # NOQA
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/pn/r4h6wncx1fj97zcdjr2jsxpw0000gn/T/pip-install-9wxy_qdj/ruamel-yaml-conda_cbc16ce42fa94f7b92437d99fa4c8484/ruamel_yaml/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
          from ruamel_yaml.main import *                               # NOQA
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/pn/r4h6wncx1fj97zcdjr2jsxpw0000gn/T/pip-install-9wxy_qdj/ruamel-yaml-conda_cbc16ce42fa94f7b92437d99fa4c8484/ruamel_yaml/main.py", line 21, in <module>
          from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO, BytesIO, with_metaclass, PY3, nprint
      ImportError: cannot import name 'PY3' from 'ruamel.yaml.compat' (/opt/miniconda3/envs/spyder/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/compat.py)
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

I did a lot of research and tried to install the package via other commands with pip;
I tried installing some dependencies of the package, but nothing seemed to work.
in the lists of packages ruamel.yaml & ruamel.yaml.clib, are present and installed.
what could be the cause of this error? how can I resolve this? does this package have special needs and dependencies? are there machine requirements for this package? is there a more accommodating version of ruamel-yaml-conda?
thank you immensely in advance for any answer.
I also have installed pip-search for good measure.
again, am a total newbe in this field and unfortunately I don't know how to read this error, so thank you in advance for any suggestion.
PS: am sorry is I misspell anything in this question; english is not my first language TwT

I think the issue is that there are two packages at play here:

ruamel-yaml-conda - you want to install this. Looking at the Pypi page, this looks like a renamed, outdated copy of 2.

ruamel.yaml - Looks to me like this is the original source, at least the description matches 1., it has more recent versions and also links to sourceforge, a more detailed description text and so forth.


The issue with your setup is that you have 2. installed, which conflicts with imports from the setup of 1.
My suggestion would be:

Make sure which of the two you want/need. I cannot judge if my assesment of one being an outdated copy of the other is correct or not.
If you do want to install ruamel-yaml-conda, then pip uninstall ruamel.yaml and only then try pip install ruamel-yaml-conda


ciao
thank you so much for your helpful suggestion.
after some checking and uninstalling the package ruamel.yaml, ruamel-yaml-conda doesn't seem to be very cooperative; thus it doesn't want to be installed at all. it keeps spitting me the same error.
so after reinstalling the ruamel.yaml package, I tried to upgrade it and to my surprise, every requirement was already satisfied. technically the machine works fine as it is (miraculously); but if you need more info to help me fix the "inconvenience", I can provide the list of installed packages in the current environment.
just let me know
